# Issue: Dropdown select not keyboard accessible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown select. I'm trying to access it via keyboard but I'm not able to highlight the options on keydown or keyup and also on pressing Enter I'm unable to select the value. Below is my HTML

```html
<dl id='amount-list' class="dropdown-add">
  <dt>
  <a href="#">                                              
   <span>
   Select Asset Type
   </span>
  </a>
 </dt>
  <dd>
    <input type="hidden" id="selected-type" name="selected-type" value="" />
    <ul id="amount-list-add">
      <li value="A" selected><a href="#" tabindex="-1">A</a></li>
      <li value="B"><a href="#" tabindex="-1">B</a></li>
      <li value="C"><a href="#" tabindex="-1">C</a></li>
      <li value="D"><a href="#" tabindex="-1">D</a></li>
      <li value="E"><a href="#" tabindex="-1">E</a></li>
      <li value="F"><a href="#" tabindex="-1">F</a></li>
      <li value="G"><a href="#" tabindex="-1">G</a></li>
    </ul>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would definitely be best to use a native HTML select element, but if you want/need to use a custom element, you're going to have to properly mark-up your element with aria-attributes/roles along with JavaScript functionality for navigation to be completely accessible. Here is an example from the W3 that accomplishes exactly what you're looking for:

```js
/**
 * @namespace aria
 */

var aria = aria || {};

/**
 * @desc
 *  Key code constants
 */
aria.KeyCode = {
  BACKSPACE: 8,
  TAB: 9,
  RETURN: 13,
  ESC: 27,
  SPACE: 32,
  PAGE_UP: 33,
  PAGE_DOWN: 34,
  END: 35,
  HOME: 36,
  LEFT: 37,
  UP: 38,
  RIGHT: 39,
  DOWN: 40,
  DELETE: 46
};

aria.Utils = aria.Utils || {};

// Polyfill src https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches
aria.Utils.matches = function(element, selector) {
  if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
    Element.prototype.matches =
      Element.prototype.matchesSelector ||
      Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
      Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector ||
      Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector ||
      Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
      function(s) {
        var matches = element.parentNode.querySelectorAll(s);
        var i = matches.length;
        while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== this) {}
        return i > -1;
      };
  }

  return element.matches(selector);
};

aria.Utils.remove = function(item) {
  if (item.remove && typeof item.remove === 'function') {
    return item.remove();
  }
  if (item.parentNode &&
    item.parentNode.removeChild &&
    typeof item.parentNode.removeChild === 'function') {
    return item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
  }
  return false;
};

aria.Utils.isFocusable = function(element) {
  if (element.tabIndex > 0 || (element.tabIndex === 0 && element.getAttribute('tabIndex') !== null)) {
    return true;
  }

  if (element.disabled) {
    return false;
  }

  switch (element.nodeName) {
    case 'A':
      return !!element.href && element.rel != 'ignore';
    case 'INPUT':
      return element.type != 'hidden' && element.type != 'file';
    case 'BUTTON':
    case 'SELECT':
    case 'TEXTAREA':
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
};

aria.Utils.getAncestorBySelector = function(element, selector) {
  if (!aria.Utils.matches(element, selector + ' ' + element.tagName)) {
    // Element is not inside an element that matches selector
    return null;
  }

  // Move up the DOM tree until a parent matching the selector is found
  var currentNode = element;
  var ancestor = null;
  while (ancestor === null) {
    if (aria.Utils.matches(currentNode.parentNode, selector)) {
      ancestor = currentNode.parentNode;
    } else {
      currentNode = currentNode.parentNode;
    }
  }

  return ancestor;
};

aria.Utils.hasClass = function(element, className) {
  return (new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)')).test(element.className);
};

aria.Utils.addClass = function(element, className) {
  if (!aria.Utils.hasClass(element, className)) {
    element.className += ' ' + className;
  }
};

aria.Utils.removeClass = function(element, className) {
  var classRegex = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)');
  element.className = element.className.replace(classRegex, ' ').trim();
};

/*
 *   This content is licensed according to the W3C Software License at
 *   https://www.w3.org/Consortium/Legal/2015/copyright-software-and-document
 */
/**
 * @namespace aria
 */
var aria = aria || {};

/**
 * @constructor
 *
 * @desc
 *  Listbox object representing the state and interactions for a listbox widget
 *
 * @param listboxNode
 *  The DOM node pointing to the listbox
 */
aria.Listbox = function(listboxNode) {
  this.listboxNode = listboxNode;
  this.activeDescendant = this.listboxNode.getAttribute('aria-activedescendant');
  this.multiselectable = this.listboxNode.hasAttribute('aria-multiselectable');
  this.moveUpDownEnabled = false;
  this.siblingList = null;
  this.upButton = null;
  this.downButton = null;
  this.moveButton = null;
  this.keysSoFar = '';
  this.handleFocusChange = function() {};
  this.handleItemChange = function(event, items) {};
  this.registerEvents();
};

/**
 * @desc
 *  Register events for the listbox interactions
 */
aria.Listbox.prototype.registerEvents = function() {
  this.listboxNode.addEventListener('focus', this.setupFocus.bind(this));
  this.listboxNode.addEventListener('keydown', this.checkKeyPress.bind(this));
  this.listboxNode.addEventListener('click', this.checkClickItem.bind(this));
};

/**
 * @desc
 *  If there is no activeDescendant, focus on the first option
 */
aria.Listbox.prototype.setupFocus = function() {
  if (this.activeDescendant) {
    return;
  }

  this.focusFirstItem();
};

/**
 * @desc
 *  Focus on the first option
 */
aria.Listbox.prototype.focusFirstItem = function() {
  var firstItem;

  firstItem = this.listboxNode.querySelector('[role="option"]');

  if (firstItem) {
    this.focusItem(firstItem);
  }
};

/**
 * @desc
 *  Focus on the last option
 */
aria.Listbox.prototype.focusLastItem = function() {
  var itemList = this.listboxNode.querySelectorAll('[role="option"]');

  if (itemList.length) {
    this.focusItem(itemList[itemList.length - 1]);
  }
};

/**
 * @desc
 *  Handle various keyboard controls; UP/DOWN will shift focus; SPACE selects
 *  an item.
 *
 * @param evt
 *  The keydown event object
 */
aria.Listbox.prototype.checkKeyPress = function(evt) {
  var key = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
  var nextItem = document.getElementById(this.activeDescendant);

  if (!nextItem) {
    return;
  }

  switch (key) {
    case aria.KeyCode.PAGE_UP:
    case aria.KeyCode.PAGE_DOWN:
      if (this.moveUpDownEnabled) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        if (key === aria.KeyCode.PAGE_UP) {
          this.moveUpItems();
        } else {
          this.moveDownItems();
        }
      }

      break;
    case aria.KeyCode.UP:
    case aria.KeyCode.DOWN:
      evt.preventDefault();

      if (this.moveUpDownEnabled && evt.altKey) {
        if (key === aria.KeyCode.UP) {
          this.moveUpItems();
        } else {
          this.moveDownItems();
        }
        return;
      }

      if (key === aria.KeyCode.UP) {
        nextItem = nextItem.previousElementSibling;
      } else {
        nextItem = nextItem.nextElementSibling;
      }

      if (nextItem) {
        this.focusItem(nextItem);
      }

      break;
    case aria.KeyCode.HOME:
      evt.preventDefault();
      this.focusFirstItem();
      break;
    case aria.KeyCode.END:
      evt.preventDefault();
      this.focusLastItem();
      break;
    case aria.KeyCode.SPACE:
      evt.preventDefault();
      this.toggleSelectItem(nextItem);
      break;
    case aria.KeyCode.BACKSPACE:
    case aria.KeyCode.DELETE:
    case aria.KeyCode.RETURN:
      if (!this.moveButton) {
        return;
      }

      var keyshortcuts = this.moveButton.getAttribute('aria-keyshortcuts');
      if (key === aria.KeyCode.RETURN && keyshortcuts.indexOf('Enter') === -1) {
        return;
      }
      if (
        (key === aria.KeyCode.BACKSPACE || key === aria.KeyCode.DELETE) &&
        keyshortcuts.indexOf('Delete') === -1
      ) {
        return;
      }

      evt.preventDefault();

      var nextUnselected = nextItem.nextElementSibling;
      while (nextUnselected) {
        if (nextUnselected.getAttribute('aria-selected') != 'true') {
          break;
        }
        nextUnselected = nextUnselected.nextElementSibling;
      }
      if (!nextUnselected) {
        nextUnselected = nextItem.previousElementSibling;
        while (nextUnselected) {
          if (nextUnselected.getAttribute('aria-selected') != 'true') {
            break;
          }
          nextUnselected = nextUnselected.previousElementSibling;
        }
      }

      this.moveItems();

      if (!this.activeDescendant && nextUnselected) {
        this.focusItem(nextUnselected);
      }
      break;
    default:
      var itemToFocus = this.findItemToFocus(key);
      if (itemToFocus) {
        this.focusItem(itemToFocus);
      }
      break;
  }
};

aria.Listbox.prototype.findItemToFocus = function(key) {
  var itemList = this.listboxNode.querySelectorAll('[role="option"]');
  var character = String.fromCharCode(key);

  if (!this.keysSoFar) {
    for (var i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
      if (itemList[i].getAttribute('id') == this.activeDescendant) {
        this.searchIndex = i;
      }
    }
  }
  this.keysSoFar += character;
  this.clearKeysSoFarAfterDelay();

  var nextMatch = this.findMatchInRange(
    itemList,
    this.searchIndex + 1,
    itemList.length
  );
  if (!nextMatch) {
    nextMatch = this.findMatchInRange(
      itemList,
      0,
      this.searchIndex
    );
  }
  return nextMatch;
};

aria.Listbox.prototype.clearKeysSoFarAfterDelay = function() {
  if (this.keyClear) {
    clearTimeout(this.keyClear);
    this.keyClear = null;
  }
  this.keyClear = setTimeout((function() {
    this.keysSoFar = '';
    this.keyClear = null;
  }).bind(this), 500);
};

aria.Listbox.prototype.findMatchInRange = function(list, startIndex, endIndex) {
  // Find the first item starting with the keysSoFar substring, searching in
  // the specified range of items
  for (var n = startIndex; n < endIndex; n++) {
    var label = list[n].innerText;
    if (label && label.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.keysSoFar) === 0) {
      return list[n];
    }
  }
  return null;
};

/**
 * @desc
 *  Check if an item is clicked on. If so, focus on it and select it.
 *
 * @param evt
 *  The click event object
 */
aria.Listbox.prototype.checkClickItem = function(evt) {
  if (evt.target.getAttribute('role') === 'option') {
    this.focusItem(evt.target);
    this.toggleSelectItem(evt.target);
  }
};

/**
 * @desc
 *  Toggle the aria-selected value
 *
 * @param element
 *  The element to select
 */
aria.Listbox.prototype.toggleSelectItem = function(element) {
  if (this.multiselectable) {
    element.setAttribute(
      'aria-selected',
      element.getAttribute('aria-selected') === 'true' ? 'false' : 'true'
    );

    if (this.moveButton) {
      if (this.listboxNode.querySelector('[aria-selected="true"]')) {
        this.moveButton.setAttribute('aria-disabled', 'false');
      } else {
        this.moveButton.setAttribute('aria-disabled', 'true');
      }
    }
  }
};

/**
 * @desc
 *  Defocus the specified item
 *
 * @param element
 *  The element to defocus
 */
aria.Listbox.prototype.defocusItem = function(element) {
  if (!element) {
    return;
  }

  aria.Utils.removeClass(element, 'focused');
};

/**
 * @desc
 *  Focus on the specified item
 *
 * @param element
 *  The element to focus
 */
aria.Listbox.prototype.focusItem = function(element) {
  this.defocusItem(document.getElementById(this.activeDescendant));
  aria.Utils.addClass(element, 'focused');
  this.listboxNode.setAttribute('aria-activedescendant', element.id);
  this.activeDescendant = element.id;

  if (this.listboxNode.scrollHeight > this.listboxNode.clientHeight) {
    var scrollBottom = this.listboxNode.clientHeight + this.listboxNode.scrollTop;
    var elementBottom = element.offsetTop + element.offsetHeight;
    if (elementBottom > scrollBottom) {
      this.listboxNode.scrollTop = elementBottom - this.listboxNode.clientHeight;
    } else if (element.offsetTop < this.listboxNode.scrollTop) {
      this.listboxNode.scrollTop = element.offsetTop;
    }
  }

  if (!this.multiselectable && this.moveButton) {
    this.moveButton.setAttribute('aria-disabled', false);
  }

  this.checkUpDownButtons();
  this.handleFocusChange(element);
};

/**
 * @desc
 *  Enable/disable the up/down arrows based on the activeDescendant.
 */
aria.Listbox.prototype.checkUpDownButtons = function() {
  var activeElement = document.getElementById(this.activeDescendant);

  if (!this.moveUpDownEnabled) {
    return false;
  }

  if (!activeElement) {
    this.upButton.setAttribute('aria-disabled', 'true');
    this.downButton.setAttribute('aria-disabled', 'true');
    return;
  }

  if (this.upButton) {
    if (activeElement.previousElementSibling) {
      this.upButton.setAttribute('aria-disabled', false);
    } else {
      this.upButton.setAttribute('aria-disabled', 'true');
    }
  }

  if (this.downButton) {
    if (activeElement.nextElementSibling) {
      this.downButton.setAttribute('aria-disabled', false);
    } else {
      this.downButton.setAttribute('aria-disabled', 'true');
    }
  }
};

/**
 * @desc
 *  Add the specified items to the listbox. Assumes items are valid options.
 *
 * @param items
 *  An array of items to add to the listbox
 */
aria.Listbox.prototype.addItems = function(items) {
  if (!items || !items.length) {
    return false;
  }

  items.forEach((function(item) {
    this.defocusItem(item);
    this.toggleSelectItem(item);
    this.listboxNode.append(item);
  }).bind(this));

  if (!this.activeDescendant) {
    this.focusItem(items[0]);
  }

  this.handleItemChange('added', items);
};

/**
 * @desc
 *  Remove all of the selected items from the listbox; Removes the focused items
 *  in a single select listbox and the items with aria-selected in a multi
 *  select listbox.
 *
 * @returns items
 *  An array of items that were removed from the listbox
 */
aria.Listbox.prototype.deleteItems = function() {
  var itemsToDelete;

  if (this.multiselectable) {
    itemsToDelete = this.listboxNode.querySelectorAll('[aria-selected="true"]');
  } else if (this.activeDescendant) {
    itemsToDelete = [document.getElementById(this.activeDescendant)];
  }

  if (!itemsToDelete || !itemsToDelete.length) {
    return [];
  }

  itemsToDelete.forEach((function(item) {
    item.remove();

    if (item.id === this.activeDescendant) {
      this.clearActiveDescendant();
    }
  }).bind(this));

  this.handleItemChange('removed', itemsToDelete);

  return itemsToDelete;
};

aria.Listbox.prototype.clearActiveDescendant = function() {
  this.activeDescendant = null;
  this.listboxNode.setAttribute('aria-activedescendant', null);

  if (this.moveButton) {
    this.moveButton.setAttribute('aria-disabled', 'true');
  }

  this.checkUpDownButtons();
};

/**
 * @desc
 *  Shifts the currently focused item up on the list. No shifting occurs if the
 *  item is already at the top of the list.
 */
aria.Listbox.prototype.moveUpItems = function() {
  var previousItem;

  if (!this.activeDescendant) {
    return;
  }

  currentItem = document.getElementById(this.activeDescendant);
  previousItem = currentItem.previousElementSibling;

  if (previousItem) {
    this.listboxNode.insertBefore(currentItem, previousItem);
    this.handleItemChange('moved_up', [currentItem]);
  }

  this.checkUpDownButtons();
};

/**
 * @desc
 *  Shifts the currently focused item down on the list. No shifting occurs if
 *  the item is already at the end of the list.
 */
aria.Listbox.prototype.moveDownItems = function() {
  var nextItem;

  if (!this.activeDescendant) {
    return;
  }

  currentItem = document.getElementById(this.activeDescendant);
  nextItem = currentItem.nextElementSibling;

  if (nextItem) {
    this.listboxNode.insertBefore(nextItem, currentItem);
    this.handleItemChange('moved_down', [currentItem]);
  }

  this.checkUpDownButtons();
};

/**
 * @desc
 *  Delete the currently selected items and add them to the sibling list.
 */
aria.Listbox.prototype.moveItems = function() {
  if (!this.siblingList) {
    return;
  }

  var itemsToMove = this.deleteItems();
  this.siblingList.addItems(itemsToMove);
};

/**
 * @desc
 *  Enable Up/Down controls to shift items up and down.
 *
 * @param upButton
 *   Up button to trigger up shift
 *
 * @param downButton
 *   Down button to trigger down shift
 */
aria.Listbox.prototype.enableMoveUpDown = function(upButton, downButton) {
  this.moveUpDownEnabled = true;
  this.upButton = upButton;
  this.downButton = downButton;
  upButton.addEventListener('click', this.moveUpItems.bind(this));
  downButton.addEventListener('click', this.moveDownItems.bind(this));
};

/**
 * @desc
 *  Enable Move controls. Moving removes selected items from the current
 *  list and adds them to the sibling list.
 *
 * @param button
 *   Move button to trigger delete
 *
 * @param siblingList
 *   Listbox to move items to
 */
aria.Listbox.prototype.setupMove = function(button, siblingList) {
  this.siblingList = siblingList;
  this.moveButton = button;
  button.addEventListener('click', this.moveItems.bind(this));
};

aria.Listbox.prototype.setHandleItemChange = function(handlerFn) {
  this.handleItemChange = handlerFn;
};

aria.Listbox.prototype.setHandleFocusChange = function(focusChangeHandler) {
  this.handleFocusChange = focusChangeHandler;
};

/**
 * ARIA Collapsible Dropdown Listbox Example
 * @function onload
 * @desc Initialize the listbox example once the page has loaded
 */

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var button = document.getElementById('exp_button');
  var exListbox = new aria.Listbox(document.getElementById('exp_elem_list'));
  var listboxButton = new aria.ListboxButton(button, exListbox);
});

var aria = aria || {};

aria.ListboxButton = function(button, listbox) {
  this.button = button;
  this.listbox = listbox;
  this.registerEvents();
};

aria.ListboxButton.prototype.registerEvents = function() {
  this.button.addEventListener('click', this.showListbox.bind(this));
  this.button.addEventListener('keyup', this.checkShow.bind(this));
  this.listbox.listboxNode.addEventListener('blur', this.hideListbox.bind(this));
  this.listbox.listboxNode.addEventListener('keydown', this.checkHide.bind(this));
  this.listbox.setHandleFocusChange(this.onFocusChange.bind(this));
};

aria.ListboxButton.prototype.checkShow = function(evt) {
  var key = evt.which || evt.keyCode;

  switch (key) {
    case aria.KeyCode.UP:
    case aria.KeyCode.DOWN:
      evt.preventDefault();
      this.showListbox();
      this.listbox.checkKeyPress(evt);
      break;
  }
};

aria.ListboxButton.prototype.checkHide = function(evt) {
  var key = evt.which || evt.keyCode;

  switch (key) {
    case aria.KeyCode.RETURN:
    case aria.KeyCode.ESC:
      evt.preventDefault();
      this.hideListbox();
      this.button.focus();
      break;
  }
};

aria.ListboxButton.prototype.showListbox = function() {
  aria.Utils.removeClass(this.listbox.listboxNode, 'hidden');
  this.button.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
  this.listbox.listboxNode.focus();
};

aria.ListboxButton.prototype.hideListbox = function() {
  aria.Utils.addClass(this.listbox.listboxNode, 'hidden');
  this.button.removeAttribute('aria-expanded');
};

aria.ListboxButton.prototype.onFocusChange = function(focusedItem) {
  this.button.innerText = focusedItem.innerText;
};
```

```css
.annotate {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #366ED4;
}

.listbox-area {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  font-size: 0px;
}

.left-area,
.right-area {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50%;
}

.left-area {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.right-area {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

[role="listbox"] {
  min-height: 18em;
  padding: 0px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

[role="option"] {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 1em;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.8em;
}

[role="option"].focused {
  background: #bde4ff;
}

[role="option"][aria-selected] {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
}

[role="option"][aria-selected="true"]::before {
  content: 'âœ“';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.5em;
}

button {
  font-size: 16px;
}

button[aria-disabled="true"] {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.move-right-btn {
  padding-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.move-right-btn::after {
  content: ' ';
  height: 10px;
  width: 12px;
  background-image: url('../imgs/Arrows-Right-icon.png');
  background-position: center right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 6px;
}

.move-left-btn {
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.move-left-btn::after {
  content: ' ';
  height: 10px;
  width: 12px;
  background-image: url('../imgs/Arrows-Left-icon.png');
  background-position: center left;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 6px;
}

#ss_elem_list {
  max-height: 18em;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#exp_button {
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

#exp_button::after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 8px solid #aaa;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 10px;
}

#exp_button[aria-expanded="true"]::after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #aaa;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 10px;
}

#exp_elem_list {
  border-top: 0;
  max-height: 10em;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  width: 148px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.toolbar {
  font-size: 0;
}

.toolbar-item {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #ccc;
}

.toolbar-item[aria-disabled="false"]:focus {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.offscreen {
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Choose your favorite transuranic element (actinide or transactinide).
</p>
<div class="listbox-area">
  <div class="left-area">
    <span id="exp_elem">
        Choose an element:
      </span>
    <div id="exp_wrapper">
      <button aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-labelledby="exp_elem exp_button" id="exp_button">
          Neptunium
        </button>
      <ul id="exp_elem_list" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" aria-labelledby="exp_elem" class="hidden">
        <li id="exp_elem_Np" role="option">
          Neptunium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Pu" role="option">
          Plutonium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Am" role="option">
          Americium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Cm" role="option">
          Curium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Bk" role="option">
          Berkelium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Cf" role="option">
          Californium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Es" role="option">
          Einsteinium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Fm" role="option">
          Fermium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Md" role="option">
          Mendelevium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_No" role="option">
          Nobelium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Lr" role="option">
          Lawrencium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Rf" role="option">
          Rutherfordium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Db" role="option">
          Dubnium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Sg" role="option">
          Seaborgium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Bh" role="option">
          Bohrium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Hs" role="option">
          Hassium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Mt" role="option">
          Meitnerium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Ds" role="option">
          Darmstadtium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Rg" role="option">
          Roentgenium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Cn" role="option">
          Copernicium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Nh" role="option">
          Nihonium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Fl" role="option">
          Flerovium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Mc" role="option">
          Moscovium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Lv" role="option">
          Livermorium
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Ts" role="option">
          Tennessine
        </li>
        <li id="exp_elem_Og" role="option">
          Oganesson
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the link](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/NOTE-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20171214/examples/listbox/listbox-collapsible.html) to the actual page.

Comment: While the link itself is helpful, your answer would not be helpful if the link were to no longer be available. Please consider providing the relevant information directly in your answer so that it is not necessary to navigate to the link in order to obtain any useful information. See [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/313880)